# incorrect seletion in Itemrenderer with checkbox

Tags: apache-flex

I am using a 'Tilelist' and 'HBOX' as itemrenderer. In the HBOX I have checkbox.

Passing arraycollection as dataprovider to TileList(my arraycollection length is 20). On selecting checkbox of item1 in the Tilelist and scroll the list I could see subsequent item as of item1 is selected. In blogs I found there is some issue of flex cache while using checkbox.

Need some help on this.

Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" verticalGap="0" xmlns:local="*" height="500" >
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var arr:Array = [
            { firstName: "Alex", lastName: "Harui" },
            { firstName: "Gordon", lastName: "Smith" },
            { firstName: "Deepa", lastName: "Subramanian" },
            { firstName: "Matt", lastName: "Chotin" },
            { firstName: "Ely", lastName: "Greenfield" },
            { firstName: "Kevin", lastName: "Lynch" },
            { firstName: "Shantanu", lastName: "Narayan" },
            { firstName: "Joan", lastName: "Lafferty" },
            { firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Frishberg" },

        ];

    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
     <mx:TileList id="list" initialize="list.dataProvider=arr" labelField="lastName" maxColumns="1" itemRenderer="Checkrenderer" 
                allowMultipleSelection="true" >

    </mx:TileList> 
</mx:Application>
```

Checkrender HBOX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="138" height="300" xmlns:local="*">
<mx:CheckBox id="checkbx"/>
</mx:Box>
</mx:HBox>
```

Comment: Are you using an item renderer? Can you post your code? You probably need to override `public function set data(value:Object)`

Comment: <mx:TileList id="list" initialize="list.dataProvider=arr" labelField="lastName" maxColumns="1" itemRenderer="Checkrenderer" 
    allowMultipleSelection="true" >

 </mx:TileList>

Comment: Checkrenderer code: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="138" height="300" xmlns:local="*">
 <mx:Box width="80%" horizontalAlign="left">
  <mx:Label id="displayName" text="{data.lastName}" color="#ffffff"/>
 </mx:Box>
 <mx:Box width="100%" horizontalAlign="right">
 <local:CheckBoxRenderer id="checkbx"/>
 </mx:Box>
</mx:HBox>

Comment: You should post your code in the question instead of in comments, that makes it impossible to read and difficult to copy.... paste the code into the question area, then highlight the code and click the {} button above the editor in stack overflow.  I'm almost positive I can answer this one without code as it's something many others have tried to do... I'll see if I can get an example thrown together quickly enough so I can just refer to it instead of attempting to explain this or point to other answers.

Comment: There is a curly bracket button in the editor.  You can highlight your code and press that to format it so it properly displays in the question.  I fixed the code formatting for you by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to keep track of the selected value on the data in the dataProvider, this is due to the fact that item renderers are "recycled" meaning they are re-used with different data applied, in order to keep track of the actual selected value for a given row it needs to be attached to the data associated with the row.  You can use the class I provided in the following example called ValueObjectWithSelected, to "wrap" any other VO/DTO by assigning it to the value property, the selected property is used to keep track of the checkbox selection and the renderer sets this property when the checkboxes selected value changes.

http://www.shaunhusain.com/CheckboxList/

http://www.shaunhusain.com/CheckboxList/srcview/

To fix your particular case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="138" height="300" xmlns:local="*">
    <mx:CheckBox id="checkbx" label="{data.firstName}" change="{data.selected = checkbx.selected}" selected="{data.selected}"/>
</mx:HBox>
```